# Importing Data in R like SAS macro

Tags: r, import

In SAS, we can write macro for importing files. The macro can be of the form:

```
%MACRO IMPORT_Data(OUT = , FILE = );

        data &OUT ;  
           infile "&INPUT_path.\&File" 
           delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767
           firstobs=2 ;

           input 
              Var1 : $10.
              Var2 : best12.
              Var3 : Percent5.2
              Var4 
              Var5 


           ;
%mend;
```

Once we have this macro, we just need to change the filename, and run the macro. We don't need to write the  import file syntax everytime we read the file. Can anybody help me to get the version in R? A reference is also greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a function()? http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/function.html

Comment: I'm not exactly looking for a function. But I got a macro option in R that can do what I'm looking for. There's some issue in that too, so putting it in answer to get some useful comments.

Comment: Not exactly your question, but if you already have SAS scripts you may find the SAScii package useful http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SAScii/

Comment: Thanks Ari! It's seems quite helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a function. A user defined function to read a specified `csv` file, apply some formatting to one or more of the columns, and return the result. Here is one example:

```
import_macro <- function(file, ...) {
data <- read.csv(file, ...)
# do whatever formatting you need to do. e.g.
data$v1 <- as.numeric(data$var1)
# var1 should be a column in your csv otherwise change it to something else
return(data)
}
```

Then you just run:

```
my_data <- import_macro('~/Desktop/file.csv', header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks Maiasaura! This one is great!

Comment: Sorry to bother you Maiasaura. But when I'm using your code I'm getting error. Maybe I'm making some mistake in "..." section. Will it be possible for you to write the complete code? I tried googling to update the code. But unfortunately I can't get the right one.Thank you!

Comment: The `...` allows you the option to pass on additional arguments to `read.csv` inside the function. So if you look up the options for `?read.csv`, you can pass those from the outside. This is the complete code. You can skip those arguments if you don't need them and just run `import_macro('C:/file.csv')`

Comment: Thanks a lot Maiasaura! It worked.  I was making a small mistake. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The following code helps me to read the data as we do in SAS. But I can't able to format my data here. So, putting the answer to get some useful comments.

```
imp<-strmacro(df,var,expr={df<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\RAW_DATA\\var.csv")})

mydata<-imp(mydata,"Import_data")  /* Data set file name*/
View(mydata)
```